# android recyclerview - TextView is not expanding properly with setmaxlines method

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview, android-linearlayout, animator

I am new to android development. For my learning purpose, I am developing an android application to list the fibonacci numbers in a recycler view. The list gets appended with new numbers as the user scrolls down the recycler view.

The image shows the app displaying the index and respective fibonacci number for the index in the recycler view

[image]

This is the layout xml of single item in recycler view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_index"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="#CDD6D5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_value"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#CDD6D5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Excerpt from the adaptor class,

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final TextView index;
        final TextView value;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            index = itemView.findViewById(R.id.info_index);
            value = itemView.findViewById(R.id.info_value);
        }
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final TextView value = holder.value;
        final TextView index = holder.index;
        value.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (value.getMaxLines() == 1000) {
                    value.setMaxLines(1);
                    notifyItemChanged(position);
                } else {
                    value.setMaxLines(1000);
                    notifyItemChanged(position);
                }
            }
        });
        Log.d(TAG, "position-value:" + String.valueOf(position));

        holder.index.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        holder.index.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));
        holder.value.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        holder.value.setText(mData.get(position));

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            holder.index.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_START);
            holder.value.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_START);
        }

    }
```

When I click on the value textview, the textview does not expand on the first click, instead I have to press two times to make it expand. The first time only the flickering happens. I have tried disabling the animator for recyclerview, tried re using the same view in the recycler view, but nothings helps.

My requirement is to expand fibonacci-value textview on click. By default it should be 1 line and when clicked it should show the whole content with multiple lines (as many as required).

currently this happens with two clicks. first time flickering and second time expands.

I believe this is a bug in android code. But just want to confirm here for any solutions that I might have missed.

Comment: Sorry what exactly is the problem here...do you want to display a multi-line textview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of the flickering is that, each time an item is clicked, just after setting maxLines, you are calling notifyItemChanged (which is the correct thing to do), but as a result, before redrawing the item onBindViewHolder is called again. So, when it is called again, there should be a way to know current max lines for that item.

Besides, if you try adding lots of items and scroll up and down, you'll see more bugs (since viewholders are reused) Thus, it is important to set/reset maxlines for each item inside onBindViewHolder (but outside click listener)

Secondly, DefaultItemAnimator of RecyclerView uses cross-fade animation when an item changes and by default, it creates two viewholders for that position for cross-fading between the two. So, above, you set a clicklistener on your "value" textview and interfere with the textview inside onClick callback. However,  when you later click and inform adapter that the item is changed, it binds the second viewholder instance. So when you click, your click is consumed with the previous "value" instance, and right afterwards a new instance is bound and you set a new clicklistener to this second viewholder instance.

This is one of many reasons that interfering with viewholder items inside the click listener is error-prone. Sometimes people solve this kind of problems with setTag/getTag but I think it is similarly error-prone as well.

I think the easiest solution is to use a **POJO** (plain old java object) for each item and include the maxLine state in this POJO. Something like FibonacciItem with fields such as int: index, String: fibonacciNumber, **boolean : expanded**. Then you will provide the list as a list of FibonacciItems. And inside your click listener, you'll update maxlines of the clicked item. Something like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
      if (mList.get(position).isExpanded()) {
          mList.get(position).setExpanded(false);
          notifyItemChanged(position);
      } else {
          mList.get(position).setExpanded(true);
          notifyItemChanged(position);
      }
```

}

And inside your onBindViewHolder, (but outside your click listener) you should set max lines for each item according to this value:

```
if(mList.get(position).isExpanded(){
    holder.value.setMaxLines(1);
 } else {
    holder.value.setMaxLines(1000);
 }
```

This will solve the issue. Besides, we usually use POJOs (or data classes) for each item in a list. It is easier to manage.

Comment: Hi Oya, thanks for the effort. Can you throw some light on how my current code is working for the second click but not the first time. As per your explanation, my code should not work for any number of clicks, but the textview expands when I click it twice.
You say, that the state should be maintained through a POJO so that during rebind we know what is the maxlines that should be set outside the onClicklistener. But I am wondering, where is the state maintained currently in my code that it works on second click but not the first time.

Comment: Good point! I logged instances of "value', your textview variable in your onBindViewHolder method and inside onClick and as I suspected they give different instances. So when you click, your click is consumed with the previous "value" instance, and right afterwards a new instance is created and you set a new clicklistener to this new instance. This explains why it doesn't work properly. Though it doesn't explain why it works in the second click.

Comment: The interesting part is, in the second click, I see that it reuses the first holder instance instead of creating a third one. As you have set this first instance correctly in your previous click, it finally gives you what you want. Try logging instances of your "value" in your onBindViewHolder method, once inside the click listener and once outside the click listener. You'll see what I mean. But I don't know why it produces two holder instances for a specific position

Comment: This is the one of many reasons that your approach, interfering with widgets inside the click listener is error-prone. Same thing I said for using setTag/getTag..  
Try also adding loots of items so that you'll need to scroll through the list. You'll observe even more bugs. Thus I recommend the approach with POJO. It's easier to manage.

Comment: That is a very good explanation. Your solution works. Thank you very much Oya :)

Comment: Great to hear it helped! My pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to repeat your issue on my device, the issue you have is that your LinearLayout is consuming your click before it reaches your textview.

Include:

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

Within your LinearLayout like so:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_index"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="#CDD6D5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_value"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#CDD6D5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Also include:

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

Within your RecyclerView

Comment: If the answer works for you please don't forget to upvote / click the green tick next to the answer to say it's correct: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: My requirement is to expand textview on click. by default it should be 1 line and when clicked it should show the whole content with multiple lines(as many as required).

Comment: Are you running this on an emulator or device?

Comment: I am running on emulator. I believe this behavior should be same across emulator and device.

Comment: Hi James, appreciate your effort. But sorry, this did not work. Thanks anyway :)